# PHP CLI stopped working

Tags: php

On my dedicated CentOS linux server my PHP CLI has stopped working. I have scripts written by a developer that require CLI and these scripts were working until yesterday. Another oddity that happened at the same time was that the symbolic link in /usr/local/bin/ to php was lost. I recreated that but it's still not working.

My developer says its not working because when we run this script from the command line;

```
<?php
echo 'php_sapi_name()='. php_sapi_name() .'<br />';
if(php_sapi_name() == 'cli' && empty($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'])) {
echo "ENVIRONMENT IS CLI";
} ELSE {
echo "ENVIRONMENT IS NOT CLI";
}
//echo phpinfo();
```

From the command line then what is returned is

```
php_sapi_name()=cgi-fcgi<br />ENVIRONMENT IS NOT CLI
```

Running php -v gives me the following output

```
PHP 5.3.8 (cgi-fcgi) (built: Feb  2 2012 14:48:13)
Copyright (c) 1997-2011 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.3.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2011 Zend Technologies
with Zend Guard Loader v3.3, Copyright (c) 1998-2010, by Zend Technologies
```

Ended up changing our script to work around this problem but it's still odd how it just changed

Comment: Someone updated/reinstalled your php ;-) And, no, we don't trust that no one changed anything :-)

Comment: try to run the script with full path of your command line php.
i.e. `/usr/local/bin/php  myscript.php`  and share the result.

Comment: I did run the script with the full path and got the result above

Comment: Maybe `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']` is set by the environment…

Comment: Sorry feeela but you lost me :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<?php
class CliCheck
{
    /**
     * Advanced PHP-CLI mode check.
     *
     * @return boolean    Returns true if PHP is running from the CLI or else false.
     *
     * @access public
     * @static
     */
    public static function isCli()
    {
        // If STDIN was not defined and PHP is running as CGI module
        // we can test for the environment variable TERM. This
        // should be a right way how to test the circumstance under
        // what mode PHP is running.
        if(!defined('STDIN') && self::isCgi()) {
            // STDIN was not defined, but if the environment variable TERM
            // is set, it is save to say that PHP is running from CLI.
            if(getenv('TERM')) {
                return true;
            }
            // Now return false, because TERM was not set.
            return false;
        }
        return defined('STDIN');
    }   

    /**
     * Simple PHP-CGI mode check.
     *
     * (DSO = Dynamic Shared Object)
     *
     * @link http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/dso.html DSO
     * @link http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.php-sapi-name.php PHP_SAPI
     *
     * @return boolean    Returns true if PHP is running as CGI module or else false.
     *
     * @access public
     * @static
     */
    public static function isCgi()
    {
        if (substr(PHP_SAPI, 0, 3) == 'cgi') {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
print "PHP is running ".((CliCheck::isCgi()) ? "as CGI modul " : ((!CliCheck::isCli()) ? "as DSO modul " : ""));
print ((CliCheck::isCli()) ? "from the CLI." : ".");
print "\n";
?>
```

Source: http://www.php.net/manual/fr/features.commandline.php#105043

Comment: PHP is running as CGI modul from the CLI